# How to properly add craftbukkit/spigot/paper as an external library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I'm having issues including bukkit/spigot/paper into my Eclipse since when I try "extends JavaPlugin" in my Class it does not seem able to import the file

I have tried versions of craftbukkit, spigot and paper on several occasions but it just does not seem to work:

[image]

[image]

From all the online tutorials I have seen, I have noticed that on their versions of eclipse the "Modulepath" and "Classpath" headings do not seem to be there, but for me they are right there:

[image: import popup]

Could someone please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: did you try classpath instead of modulepath?

Comment: another option might be to use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle and import the Spigot API like that.

Answer (score 1):

As an advanced user I recommend IntelliJ IDEA, it handles all the dependencies automatically, so you don't have to. When you have it installed, just download the "Minecraft Development" plugin and create a new project with it.

Comment: I'm also a IntelliJ user, but OP asked for a solution for Eclipse.

Comment: yes i know but i don‘t recommend eclipse otherwise there are really cool tutorials on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Intellij IDEA and there is a plugin that create all the file on it, if you really want a clean environment use this to create your project and go back on eclipse after, i can create it and send you the main folder if you can provide you paper version that you want

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `paper` as a External JAR. Instead download `Bukkit` or `Spigot` from the internet (or use [BuildTools](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/) to compile your own jar file), and use those instead of paper.